# Mapping Between Two DataFrames Into A New Schema'd Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to find a efficient and clean way to create a schema'd DataFrame among two other DataFrames.

DataFrame One (fNameDF):

```
+---------+
| fName   |
+---------+
| Paul    |
| Bob     |
| George  |
+---------+
```

DataFrame Two (lNameDF):

```
+---------+
| lName   |
+---------+
| Rimerman|
| King    |
| Reed    |
+---------+
```

Outcome: DataFrame Three (combinedDF):

```
val combinedSchema: StructType = new StructType()
.add(StructField("fullName", StringType, nullable = true))
.add(StructField("phoneNumber", StringType, nullable = true))

+-----------------+--------------+
|     fullName    | phoneNumber  |
+-----------------+--------------+
| Paul Rimerman   |     null     |
| Paul King       |     null     |
| Paul Reed       |     null     |
| Bob Rimerman    |     null     |
| Bob King        |     null     |
| Bob Reed        |     null     |
| George Rimerman |     null     |
| George King     |     null     |
| George Reed     |     null     |
+-----------------+--------------+
```

I have attempted- with no luck- accomplishing the above using a nested mapping operation, but feel as if there is simpler way of doing this?

```
val combinedDF = fNameDF.map(fNameRow => { lNameDF.map(lNameRow => 
{ val fullName = concat(fNameDF.getString(0),lit(" "), lNameDF.getString(0))})}).schema(combinedSchema)
```

Comment: Use `CrossJoin`

Comment: Ah yes totally makes sense to use CrossJoin for generate a cartesian product set and then do a concat of columns on that set into a schema'd DF. Thanks @blackbishop!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `full join`:

```
scala> var df = Seq(("Rimerman"),("King"),("ReedReed"),("Mahesh")).toDF("lname").withColumn("id",lit(1))

scala> df.show()
+--------+---+
|   lname| id|
+--------+---+
|Rimerman|  1|
|    King|  1|
|ReedReed|  1|
|  Mahesh|  1|
+--------+---+
```

for more understanding, you can remove `drop` clause from `join` statement

```
scala> var df2 = Seq(("George"),("Bob"),("Paul")).toDF("fname").withColumn("id",lit(1))

scala> df2.show
+------+---+
| fname| id|
+------+---+
|George|  1|
|   Bob|  1|
|  Paul|  1|
+------+---+

scala> df.join(df2,Seq("id"),"full").drop("id").withColumn("full_name",concat(col("fname"),lit(" "),col("lname"))).withColumn("phone_number",lit("Null")).drop("lname","fname").orderBy(col("full_name")).show

+---------------+------------+
|      full_name|phone_number|
+---------------+------------+
|       Bob King|        Null|
|     Bob Mahesh|        Null|
|   Bob ReedReed|        Null|
|   Bob Rimerman|        Null|
|    George King|        Null|
|  George Mahesh|        Null|
|George ReedReed|        Null|
|George Rimerman|        Null|
|      Paul King|        Null|
|    Paul Mahesh|        Null|
|  Paul ReedReed|        Null|
|  Paul Rimerman|        Null|
+---------------+------------+
```

hope it helps you.